# OneDrive REST API download returns 200 instead of 302

Tags: onedrive

I am accessing OneDrive from a C++ program using WinHttp* functions. What absolutely baffles me is [REST API download command](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/download.htm). I am downloading a small test picture with

```
GET /v1.0/drive/items/FF306293D40F9529!158/content
```

When I do this in the [console](https://apigee.com/OneDrive/embed/console/OneDrive), I get a response exactly as described in the docs, that is, a 302 redirect to the actual content. However when I send the same request with WinHttpSendRequest, I receive the actual file contents instead of a redirection:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public
Date: Wed, 06 Jan 2016 10:22:36 GMT
Content-Length: 161796
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Location: https://public-bn1306.files.1drv.com/blahblahbla
Expires: Tue, 05 Apr 2016 10:22:36 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 06 Jan 2016 10:22:35 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: aRkYzMDYyOTNENDBGOTUyOSExNTguMw
P3P: CP="BUS CUR CONo FIN IVDo ONL OUR PHY SAMo TELo"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-MSNSERVER: BN1306____PAP099
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-SqlDataOrigin: S
CTag: aYzpGRjMwNjI5M0Q0MEY5NTI5ITE1OC4yNTc
X-PreAuthInfo: rv;poba;
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Test.jpg"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-StreamOrigin: X
X-AsmVersion: UNKNOWN; 19.33.0.0
X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: 44F40B6FB83547EFBC895911207BDB42 Ref B: 96336B0FC1B608598B549A1CB70C8C59 Ref C: Wed Jan 06 02:22:36 2016 PST
```

First I thought that maybe it was because the file was small, but trying to download a 250Mb large binary file changed nothing.

I don't complain actually, this would make the program a bit simpler, but I certainly would like to know why the same request works differently with WinHttp*. I suppose I do something wrong, but what??? (Banging my head against my desk.)

Answer (score 0):

There are http libraries that will follow redirects automatically. You send a request, the library receives 302, and decides on its own to go to the redirect location, which then returns a 200.

Comment: gnasher729, thanks, but it does not seem to be the case. A more detailed reply above.